# How do I find duplicate indices in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a pandas DataFrame with a multi-level index ("instance" and "index"). I want to find all the first-level ("instance") index values which are non-unique and to print out those values.

My frame looks like this:

```
                     A
instance  index      
      a       1      10
              2      12
              3      4
      b       1      12
              2      5
              3      2 
      b       1      12
              2      5
              3      2
```

I want to find "b" as the duplicate 0-level index and print its value ("b") out.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `get_duplicates()` method:

```
>>> df.index.get_level_values('instance').get_duplicates()
[0, 1]
```

(In my example data `0` and `1` both appear multiple times.)

The `get_level_values()` method can accept a label (such as 'instance') or an integer and retrieves the relevant part of the MultiIndex.

Comment: It doesnt work. The reason might be the multi-index: I have multiple sub-indices (e.g. 0,1,2,3,4) and the get_level_values() method seems to get the top level indices from "instance" more than once, one time for each sub-level index:`('a','0') , ('a','1'), ('a','2'), ('a','3'), ('a','4')`. The index a will be counted 5 times, therefore **every** top level index is a duplicate.

Comment: So you only want to count `'a'` once in that example? So if you had the 0 level index as `['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a']` you'd say `'a'` appeared twice and `'b'` only once (or have I misunderstood)?

Comment: I edited the question with an example of my df. The index "b" appears twice,  and i want it to print out "duplicate indices: b"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `df` has an index made of `'instance'` and `'index'` you could do this:

```
df1 = df.reset_index().pivot_table(index=['instance','index'], values='A', aggfunc='count')
df1[df1 > 1].index.get_level_values(0).drop_duplicates()
```

Which yields:

```
Index([u'b'], dtype='object')
```

Adding `.values` at the end (`.drop_duplicates().values`) will make an array:

```
array(['b'], dtype=object)
```

Or the same with one line using `.groupby`:

```
df[df.groupby(level=['instance','index']).count() > 1].dropna().index.get_level_values(0).drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the whole row which isn't quite what you asked for but might be close enough:

`df[df.index.get_level_values('instance').duplicated()]`

Answer (score 1):

To see the rows with duplicated index:

```
duplicated = df[df.index.duplicated()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the duplicated method:

```
df['Instance'].duplicated()
```

Comment: This does not really work. "instance" is a index-column, so i cant access it via df["instance"]. df.loc["instance"] doesnt seem to work either...

Comment: Try df.ix['instance'].